# Dns over TLS.Someting wrong with connection

Tags: android, dns, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

In Android system, when a network switch occurs, due to the involvement of NAT (Network Address Translation) from private network to public network, there may be changes in IP and port. This can lead to the SSL connections established in DNSResolver becoming ineffective. From the captured packet information, it seems that the DNS request packets sent by the client keep retransmitting. However, it is strange that the return value of the SSLwrite function is greater than 0, indicating a successful write, but according to the packet capture, the SSLwrite function did not actually send the packet. Additionally, when sending a packet to an invalidated SSL socket, one would normally expect to receive a RESET packet, but in reality, no RESET packet is received.

```
bool DnsTlsSocket::sslWrite(const Slice buffer) {
    LOG(DEBUG) << mMark << " Writing " << buffer.size() << " bytes";
    for (;;) {
        int ret = SSL_write(mSsl.get(), buffer.base(), buffer.size());
        if (ret == int(buffer.size())) break;  // SSL write complete;

        if (ret < 1) {
            const int ssl_err = SSL_get_error(mSsl.get(), ret);
            switch (ssl_err) {
                case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                    if (int err = waitForWriting(mSslFd.get()); err <= 0) {
                        PLOG(WARNING) << "Poll failed in sslWrite, error " << err;
                        return false;
                    }
                    continue;
                case 0:
                    break;  // SSL write complete;
                default:
                    LOG(DEBUG) << "SSL_write error " << ssl_err;
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    LOG(DEBUG) << mMark << " Wrote " << buffer.size() << " bytes";
    return true;
}
```

Packets
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBToT.png)

I tried to analyze but couldn't find the root cause. Can someone give me some ideas?